# How to implement list items with floated icon that doesn't allow text to flow under it?

Tags: javascript, html, css

What i'm trying to override

[image: Not desired behavior]

What i want to get

[image: Desired behavior]

!IMPORTANT: Li elements shouldn't have left padding. Or they should get it automatically without attaching class to them.

I want it such a way because of situation described below.
Imaging you have list with 50 list elements, 30 of them should have icon (and left padding)
20 no. You have to attach class to each list element that has icon, or that has no icon, to make it has no padding.

Of course we can use JavaScript, but what about css? I have seen such an example, but have lost it.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
li .icon{margin-left:-20px;position:absolute;}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/fRG4H/

Comment: That one is better. Will try to remember now, why i didn't go that way, i had a problem with negative margin there.

Comment: But, we have another solution for that yep? using li:after; 
http://jsfiddle.net/r8xCU/

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
ul {
list-style: none url('path of image');
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, do you think it will work if you need a bigger image, what if you will need to adjust image position. I think there is no such a property for list element.

Comment: And yes, of course list elements could be a div's. We can implement lists using other elements rather then UL and LI

Answer (score 0):

you can also try this

```
ul li {
      list-style: url(path of image);
      list-style-position: outside;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is if you can wrap the other content in another container like this:

```
<li>
    <i class="icon">❤</i>
    <span>Lorem ipsum dorem fasid ipsum dorem fasid</span>
</li>
```

...you can use `inline-block` like so:

```
li > * { display:inline-block; vertical-align:top }
li > span { max-width:90% }
```

---

[image]

---

The `width:90%` can be adjusted, just make sure you leave some room for the icon.

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/PZLrb/**

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Yes, it can be implemented by your way. But it's the same as attaching class to the list or list-item. Like 
<li class="donk-float-icon"> 

then we have li { padding-left:icon-width} i {position:absolute;top:0;left:0;}

I saw the example without affecting class and li content padding. Like:

i {display:inline-block; height:100%} (but that one doesn't work, it's just my toughts)

I hope you understand what i'm looking for. That one example that, you have added below. Is better, but i got another problem with that, i forgot what is it actually )